# Nodejs: Run a function in an arbitrary module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a directory full of javascript files:

```
.
+-- my_dir
    +-- apple.js
    +-- banana.js
+-- main.js
```

And each file in the subdirectory contains a function called `setup()`.

How can I iterate through all the files and run that function?

This is as far as I've got:

```
var fruit = {}
var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "fruit");

require("fs").readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
  filename = file.split(".")[0] //remove the file extension
  algorithms[filename] = require("./fruit/" + file); //load the file
  //run the setup function in it
  algorithms[filename].setup()
});
```

But this can't access the function, returning "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Are you exporting `setup()` from each of your modules?

Comment: That fixed it! Schoolboy error :D

Comment: Will accept once the time limit is gone

Comment: I'm too fast for SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export `setup()` from each of your modules.

a-module.js

```
var obj = {};

obj.setup = function(){
    // doStuff
}

module.exports = obj
```

Comment: Or just `exports.setup = function() { console.log('hello world'); };`